# Tensorflow error [image not found]

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I installed tensorflow ver1.0.0 but it did not work!!
I use Python3.6.0, Tensorflow-gpu-1.0.0. Please tell me how to fix it!

```
~/Desktop/tensorflow $ source ~/Desktop/tensorflow/bin/activate
 (tensorflow) ~/Desktop/tensorflow $ python
Python 3.6.0 (default, Feb 17 2017, 14:31:13)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ubeat0n/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Users/ubeat0n/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/ubeat0n/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Users/ubeat0n/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Users/ubeat0n/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/ubeat0n/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/ubeat0n/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ubeat0n/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Users/ubeat0n/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ubeat0n/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Users/ubeat0n/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/ubeat0n/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Users/ubeat0n/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Users/ubeat0n/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/ubeat0n/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/ubeat0n/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See     https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>>
```

seems above, I was able to install tensorflow, and activate tensorflow-gpu 1.0.0....
In reference to other similar question in stackoverflow, I disable csrutil!
    csrutil disable

Wasn't tensorflow installed..??

Comment: Seems I could install CUDA!

Comment: (tensorflow) ~/Desktop/tensorflow $ brew cask info cuda
cuda: 8.0.55
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-zone
/usr/local/Caskroom/cuda/8.0.55 (23 files, 1.3G)
From: https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/cuda.rb
==> Name
Nvidia CUDA
==> Artifacts
(tensorflow) ~/Desktop/tensorflow $

Comment: Please follow up in github for install issues, and make sure you follow the instructions in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error by adding

```
$export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib\
                     ${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

like in the CUDA Installation Guide.